# Sticking caliper - free off or replace?

Tags: brakes, nissan, brake-calipers

The other day, one of the front calipers on my wife's Micra stuck, causing the brake on that wheel to drag. I freed it off by winding the piston in and pumping it back out a few times, until it went in and out freely, and the brakes are now working correctly, however I'm wondering if it's just going to stick again pretty soon - in which case it'd be better to replace it with new? I couldn't see any sign of damage to the seals that could have allowed moisture into the piston, but the car doesn't get a lot of use.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this where is was just a build up of dried up brake fluid baked into a ridge on the piston.  Cleaning it off solved the problem.  Your pushing the piston in and out may have rubbed it off.

If it is not leaking, I would just keep an eye on it for a while.

Comment: There were definitely no leaks, that was one of the first things I checked!

Comment: @NickC it might be an idea to get an overhaul kit for the caliper and change the rubber seals and clean and lube the piston/cylinder.